# Esqueleto: how to apply lower_ to maybe field?

Tags: haskell, esqueleto

How to apply function `lower_` to `(Value (Maybe typ))`?
I have maybe string field in db, so after `(^.)` operator I'll have expression with type: `SqlExpr (Value (Maybe String))`.
Let us suppose lower_ is `SqlExpr (Value String) -> SqlExpr (Value String)`.
How to apply `lower_` for this?

Comment: What should happen if the expression is `Nothing`?

Comment: `lower` has type `expr (Value a) -> expr (Value a)`. It should work fine on a `Value (Maybe typ)`.